# If VP becomes POTUS, how often can he be elected as president afterwards

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-election, vice-president, presidential-term

In the USA one can only be president for two legislative periods. Also, when a president is removed from office or dies, the vice president becomes president.
Does this count as the VP's first term or can he still be presidential candidate for two further times?

Comment: @CDJB thanks for linking the original question. I can't delete this one, would you kindly do that for me?

Comment: Duplicates aren't necessarily bad. Why would you want to delete this question?

Comment: @SeverusSnape Just to minimize the size of the internet :D

Comment: "legislative periods" is perhaps the wrong term, since the house of representatives has two-year terms and the president is limited, in general, to two four-year terms.

Comment: @phoog I'm not a native speaker. What would be the correct terminology? Feel free to edit the question.